# React / Redux - Get Details from Url ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Im making a portfolio.

I have a list of works in my http://localhost:8080/works

When i click "Know more" button, i want to go to a different url that shows me more info about that particular work.

For that i think i need to get the ID from the url.

Im trying to use AXIOS to make a get request but its not working...So i decided to start again.

Could some one help me ?

**actions/index.js**

```
export function workFetch(id) {

    return {
        type: 'WORK_FETCH',
        payload: request
    };

}
```

**containers/trabalhos.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class Trabalhos extends Component {


renderList(){

    return this.props.trabalhos.map((trabalho) => {
        return(

            <li key={trabalho.id}>                 
                    <img src={trabalho.img} />
                    <p className="trabalho_titulo">{trabalho.title}</p>
                    <p className="trabalho_desc">{trabalho.descricao}</p>
                <Link to={"trabalhos/" + trabalho.id}>    
                    <a className="trabalho_saber_mais">Saber Mais</a>
                </Link>
            </li>

        );
    });
}


render(){

    return (

        <div>
            <div className="trabalhos">
                <div className="trabalhos_caixa">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <ul className="no_pad">
                                {this.renderList()}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {

        trabalhos: state.trabalho

    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Trabalhos);
```

**containers/trabalhos_show.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TrabalhosShow extends Component {

    render(){
        return (

            <div>

                <li>Show post: {this.props.params.id}</li>
                <li>Descrição: {this.props.params.descricao}</li>

            </div>

            )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    data: state.trabalho[props.params.id],
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrabalhosShow);
```

**Reducers**

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import TrabalhoPortofolio from './reducer_trabalhos';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    trabalho: TrabalhoPortofolio
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**reducers/reducer_trabalhos.js**

```
export default function() {

    return [

        { id: 1, title: 'Miristica', tec: "Wordpress-Woocommerce", descricao: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", img: 'http://feiraalternativa.pt/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Miristica-Bio-Cosm%C3%A9tica.png'},
        { id: 2, title: 'Teste', tec: "Wordpress-Woocommerce", descricao: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/766360293953802240/kt0hiSmv.jpg'},

    ];

}
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import Index from './components/index';
import Trabalhos from './containers/trabalhos';
import TrabalhosShow from './containers/trabalhos_show';

export default (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index} />
    <Route path="trabalhos" component={Trabalhos}/>
    <Route path="trabalhos/:id" component={TrabalhosShow} />
</Route>
);
```

Once again the objective is when i click the work or in the Know more Button, i want to go to the single page based on the ID.

I want to show the info of that particular ID.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your current problem? Seems like you already get the `id` in `TrabalhosShow`?

Comment: Yes i have the id, but i want to get the rest of the info that is in my reducer, base on the id from the url. I want to get the picture and the description etc...

Comment: what happens in your browser (also see browser console) when you click "Know More" button now?

Comment: I think i need do go by the ID on the Url, make a get, im using Axios. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect `TrabalhosShow` similar to `Trabalhos`. Note that you can also [access the passed props in `mapStateToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), so no need to connect to the whole state:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    data: state.trabalho[props.params.id]
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrabalhosShow);
```

The entity will be passed to your component in the prop `data`, e.g. `this.props.data.title` will return the title.

Comment: inyono thanks for the help. but its not working, or im not understanding...I will update my trabalhos.show.js in my question for you to see what im doing wrong. thank you very much

Comment: Because of `data: state.trabalho[props.params.id]`, you have to access the entity with `this.props.data`. So `this.props.params.descricao` should be `this.props.data.descricao`. IMHO, it's often helpful to log `this.props` to see what's happening.

Comment: inoyono, now i can get the this.props.params.descricao , but its the same for all the works, i think i need do go by the id on the url. im trying to make a GET whit Axios. but its not working too :(

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Like you said, you have access to the entity. Furthermore, you have access to the id through `this.props.params.id` (which is the id in the URL btw) that you might use in a GET request (if this is what you want to achieve).

Comment: Yes, i want to make a GET request based on that ID, when i click the Know More button , than it sends me to http://www.localhost:8080/trabalhos/1 or http://www.localhost:8080/trabalhos/2 , and gets me the info from that id

Comment: For what exactly? So do you want to have an external API? Because currently, there is no need for a GET request since you already obtain the data through the Redux store and redux-router handles the transition to route that shows the details.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I have try your solution, but its not working. When i click the Know more button , it shows me the same for all of my works

Comment: Do i need to make an if statement on my reducer, if id== action.id , what do you think ?